# What is Causing INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD Error in Queueable Class?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, queueable-apex

### Goal

My goal is to create a reusable **Apex action/invokable method** to allow a flow to asynchronously insert/update/delete a collection of records using the **queueable interface**.

Note that I am aware of the pause flow interview functionality, but it doesn't meet my requirements.

### Issue

When the **queueable class** tries to perform an update DML on a collection of Account records that was passed on by an **invokable method** that received it from a **flow**, the following exception is thrown:

> Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0012w00000K5uvLAAR;
> first error: INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD, SLA: value not of
> required type: Gold: [SLA__c]

Debug logs:

[image: Debug logs]

### Setup

This is my code for the **invokable method**:

```
public with sharing class OperateOnSobjects {

    @InvocableMethod(label='Future Operation' description='Inserts/updates/deletes the records specified using a future call.' category= 'Other')
    public static void callQueueableClass (List<Request> requestList) {

        List<SObject> inputCollection = requestList[0].inputCollection;
        String operation = requestList[0].operation;
        
        AsyncExecution asyncJob = new AsyncExecution(inputCollection, operation);
        ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(asyncJob);
        
    }
     
    public class Request {
        @InvocableVariable(label='Records for Input' description='The record collection variable for the inputs.' required=true)
        public List<SObject> inputCollection;

        @InvocableVariable(label='Operation' description='The operation that should be performed on the inputs.' required=true)
        public String operation;
    }
}
```

This is my code for the **queueable class**:

```
public with sharing class AsyncExecution implements Queueable {

    private List<SObject> sobjects;
    String operation;
    
    public AsyncExecution(List<SObject> records, String opp) {
        this.sobjects = records;
        this.operation = opp;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        switch on operation {
            when 'Insert' {
                insert sobjects;
            }
            when 'Update' {
                System.debug('Updating ==> ' + sobjects);
                update sobjects;
            }
            when 'Delete' {
                delete sobjects;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my **flow**:

[image: Flow elements]

[image: Set SLA assignment element]

[image: Add to collection assignment element]

[image: Apex action element]

### Things I've Tried

1. Casting the sobjects collection into an Account collection (in the execute method of the queueable class) and then trying to update.
2. Updating all collections to be Account collections (in both the invokable method and queueable class).
3. Updating the assignemnt element in the flow to set a new value for a Number field (instead of the SLA picklist field).

In all of the above scenarios, the exact same exception was thrown.

### Question

What is causing the INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD exception and how can I avoid it?

### References

I based my code for the **invokable method** and **queueable class** on the examples provided here:

- [InvocableMethod Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) - Refer to the example of an invocable method with the generic sObject data type.
- [Control Processes with Queueable Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_queueable) - Refer to the code under the 'Sample Code' heading.

Comment: what is variable type from flow? It seems SLA is not treating as String. If possible add type check of SLA field in debug. And +1 for the neat question with details and formatting.